# Android ProgessDialog weird console error message

Tags: java, android

I have a simple ProgessDialog. I show the dialog, call a method and later inside the method I hide the dialog but I am getting a console error.

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ChangeEmailActivity.this);
progressDialog.setTitle("Loading");
progressDialog.show();
```

Inside the method

```
progressDialog.hide();
```

> E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity de.at_c.liftkey.ChangeEmailActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{10f2f3a8 G.E..... R.....ID 0,0-729,322} that was originally added here
>                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
>                                                                     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:271)
>                                                                     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
>                                                                     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
>                                                                     at de.at_c.liftkey.ChangeEmailActivity$1.onClick(ChangeEmailActivity.java:42)
>                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
>                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
>                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: This is because some where in your activity you are navigating to a different activity. and later trying to call hide on your previous activity. The progressDialog belongs to ChangeEmailActivity . You need to be on that activity to perform any type of action. Please post code for that method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Instead of

```
progressDialog.hide();
```

You need to dismiss the dialog instead of hiding it.

Answer (score 0):

Try running progressBar.dismiss() before the activity or fragment holding it is destroyed. Can always put it in the onDestroy() method.